# Loading from one persistance unit and persisting in another

Tags: hibernate, jboss, jpa-2.0, java-ee-6

I have a problem with Hibernate/JPA, a problem when the magic behind the scene makes life difficult. What I would like to do is very trivial so there should be a solution for this but I just can't find it.

So I would like to load some tables from one persistance unit (database) and store them into another persistance unit (another database). There is nothing funny going on here just load and persist.

In my first attempt I used *persist* to store the detached entities in a new persistance unit. It didn't work as they already have identifiers so I had to try something else.

So my second attempt is to used *merge* but this resulted in Hibernate doing one (at least) *select* per entity extra. Using the *merge* caused this to be extremely slow and in the end not usable for us.

So to my question, is there anyway of persisting detached entities in a new persistance unit without using *merge*? I already know that the tables are empty so I don't need hibernate to check it for me...

Comment: What I guess I would like to do here is to make detached entities transient, so they can be persisted and not merged. Is there anyway one can do this? How do Hibernate detect if a entity is detached (is identifier set)? I would like to keep the identifiers if it is possible.

Comment: I found the following section in the Hibernate documentation "Replicating object between two different datastores", so should be possible with plain Hibernate. However I have still not found a way to do it with JPA.

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
Entity e = em1.load(id);
em1.detach(e);
e.setId(0); // or null
em2.persist(e);
```

You'll have to make `setId` visible to this code of course.

If you're trying to implement replication for everything, doing it in the actual databases is probably a better idea (i.e. use whatever cluster features your DBMS has).

#### Edit:

Another option would be to implement a (deep) copy constructor for your entities.

```
Entity e1 = em1.load(id);
Entity e2 = new Entity(e1);
em2.persist(e2);
```

Comment: if this actually works, and you are using a version column, you'll probably also want to null that out too.

Comment: The important thing is that the entities are considered _transient_ by Hibernate. I know that identifier is involved in this, by historical reasons maybe, but it can not be the only thing. If an entity was considered _transient_ only by identifier it would be impossible to persist entities non-generated identifiers (which it is not case). So there has to be a more complex definition of _transient_ state?

Comment: I could also add to this that I have tried to use _persist_ with entities that are detached (by removing the generate-id annotation). All the entities was persisted but not the connections (all FK was null)...

Comment: @Peter Eriksson - You'd probably have to detach all the children too. I'd still recommend a proper replication system rather than trying to fool Hibernate in this way.